# invalid argument supplied for foreach() when i try to display the auth user data

Tags: php, laravel

hello i have two tables with this relationship :
User model :

```php
public function OneYearBodys()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OneYearBody');
}
```

OneYearBody model :

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

the controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $Bodies = OneYearBody::all();
    return view('OneYear.Body')->with('Bodies',$Bodies);
}
```

Now i need to display the data for the specific logged-in user who created this data, i already stock his id in the database
so i have tried this :

```xml
@foreach (Auth::user()->Bodies as $body)
    {{ $body->OneYearBody }}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

but i'm getting this error : `invalid argument supplied for foreach()`
and when i display the data for all users its work when i do this :

```xml
@foreach ($Bodies as $body)
    {{ $body->OneYearBody }}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `Auth::user()->Bodies` isn't returning an iterable; it's likely `null` since you don't have a `public function bodies()` on your `User` model.

Comment: yes thank you that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the relationship as `public function OneYearBodys() { ... }` so you should be iterating over it with that name. `@foreach (Auth::user()->OneYearBodys as $body)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the following

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->Bodies as $body)
                        {{ $body->OneYearBody }}
                        <br>
                        @endforeach
```

You would need to add a Bodies relationship to your user model. Or change Bodies to OneYearBodys